# How do i estimate the Weights of the predictions assigned to each of the tree in GBM using R? How does GBM split nodes?

Tags: machine-learning, cart, boosting

1. I ran a GBM model in R with loss function as bernoulli and n.trees=1000. I want to see the weights assigned to the predictions coming from 1000 trees. Is there any command in R that does that?
2. How does GBM split nodes while constructing trees? How does it determine the first variable to split while building classification tree? Does it use the gini index or information gain?
3. Is Gradient descent algorithm used to estimate the weights for the predictions coming from each tree? If not, what is used for?